# Generating PDF Symfony2 IoTcpdfBundle

Tags: pdf, symfony

I'm generating pdf file with IoTcpdfBundle using Symfony2, but there's a strange behaviour that I don't understand.

When I'm on the controller, I generate the pdf file like this:

```
$html = $this->renderView('MyBundle:Docs:solicituddevacaciones.pdf.twig', array());
return $this->get('io_tcpdf')->quick_pdf($html);
```

Those lines generate the pdf file. Everything's fine, I can right click on the file to save it and it's a .pdf file.

But when I receive some data using a form, and I put the lines inside the:

```
if ($request->getMethod() == 'POST') {
    $year = $this->get('request')->request->get('year');
    $date= $this->get('request')->request->get('date');

    $html = $this->renderView('SoflaSoflaBundle:Documentales:solicituddevacaciones.pdf.twig', array());
    return $this->get('io_tcpdf')->quick_pdf($html);        
}
```

When I right click on the file to save it, it's not a .pdf file, the browser suggests that I should save the file as a .htm

Why is this happening? I need users to be able to save the files as .pdf files.

Need help with this please.

Comment: this is the weirdest problem ever and I haven't been able to solve it yet...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had some similar problems and found out that the bundle might be outdated by now. I had to change some of the settings, most importantly adding another header to quick_pdf function of Tcpdf class in 'Helper' folder of the bundle:

```
 $response->headers->set('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename="'.$file.'"');
```

Now it's working like a charm, calling it in the controller like:

```
        $html = $this->renderView('Bundle:Item:print.pdf.twig', array(
        'some' => $this->value,
    ));

    return $this->get('io_tcpdf')->quick_pdf($html, "yourFileName.pdf");
```

Comment: Thank you buddy, it works amazing, but I would like the user to be able to preview the document before it is saved. 

I would like to preview the file and be able to right click and save. This solve a 50% of the problem that I had, :). So thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try to save the html (or better yet, left click instead of right click) and check the contents of that file. You probably have an error in ther somewhere, and that html file is the one generated by symfony to explain the error.

Comment: when I save the .html, what I have is the view that brought me to the pdf. 
When I select the contents of the ".pdf" file, I have the text that I want. But I'm not able to save it as a .pdf :(. I believe I have no errors because the .pdf generates itself perfectly both ways, receiving POST data and with static content, but when receiving POST data it doesn't allow me to save the file as a .pdf.

Comment: I've tried forwarding to another controller after receiving POST values but the behaviour is the same...